# Hashing algorithms

Tags: hash

How can you tell which hashing algorithm is being used on a system? We are using 2048 bit encryption and wondering how to tell if hashing algorithm SHA-1 with SHA-2 is being used.

Answer (score 2):

Well, first of, hashing does not actually help in encryption (strictly speaking, it can, with OAEP padding, but I strongly doubt that applies to your case). I *suppose* that what you call "encryption" is actually a [digital signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature). Digital signatures are unfortunately often described as "encryption with the private key", which is a flawed analogy, since it works only for RSA, and does not actually work for RSA, only "sort-of". It is an historical pedagogical gimmick which has gone wrong decades ago, and is endlessly parroted by hordes of bloggers and ill-informed teachers, leaving the common bystander stuck in a gloomy swamp of mental confusion.

Therefore, assuming that you really want to talk about *signatures*, your question becomes clearer. You are using RSA-based signatures, and a RSA signature generation or verification begins with *hashing*; the RSA magic with the modular exponentiation comes only afterwards, and works with the hash value.

Since whoever *verifies* the signature must also compute the hash value, which hash function to use is not normally a secret. Most signature formats include a header which specifies it. For instance, if you look at a X.509 certificate and decode it with [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/), the command-line tool will print out the signature value with something like this:

```
$ openssl x509 -text -noout -in cert.pem
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 14070511318992561002 (0xc3447f7ef0aa236a)
(...)
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
         93:00:8e:ac:16:77:3c:dc:ba:89:fc:63:5f:74:c7:bb:72:3a:
         6c:af:26:eb:62:04:5b:65:37:cf:c2:41:8e:de:03:db:20:c4:
```

The `sha1WithRSAEncryption` states quite clearly that in this case, RSA is being used with SHA-1 as underlying hash function.

**If you are doing some reverse-engineering** and such a header does not appear to be available, you may still infer it from a signature value, provided that you have the public key around, and are not afraid to do some computation on big integers. Namely, most RSA signatures out there will use [PKCS#1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447), and more precisely the "old-style v1.5 padding". With this padding, a signature generation does thus:

1. The message *m* is hashed into *h(m)*.
2. *h(m)* is stored in a structure which includes an explicit header identifying the hash function.
3. The resulting structure is left-padded by adding, in that order, a byte of value 0x00, a byte of value 0x01, many bytes of value 0xFF, then a byte of value 0x00.
4. The resulting padded string is interpreted as a big integer modulo *n* (*n* is the RSA modulus, part of the key pair), and subject to the modular exponentiation which is at the core of RSA.

Using a given signature *s*, and the public key *(n, e)* (*n* is the "modulus", *e* is the "public exponent"), you can recompute *s<sup>e</sup>* mod *n* and this should yield the "padded sequence", which is recognizable due to its long sequence of 0xFF bytes; and then you can see the structure header which identifies the hash function, exactly the information which you are after.

When I must do such things, I use my Linux-based laptop because it comes with the [`dc`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dc) tool, a nifty command-line calculator which handles big integers (including modular exponentiation) and hexadecimal input/output.

In any case, see PKCS#1 for details. You cannot hope to do such investigations seriously without acquiring some reasonable grasp of the inner functioning of RSA, and PKCS#1 is a good place to start.

**Anyway**, since both the signature *generation* system, and the signature *verification* system, must agree on the hash function to use, this gives you two places where you can look for the information.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, by looking at a *hashed sequence*, determine what kind of hash did generate it. If you could, that would strongly hint at a non-randomness - even worse, *recognizability* - of the hash, which would make it less useful for security purposes.

You can however tell between a SHA-1 or SHA-2 *hashed value* from its length. SHA-1 is 160 bits (20 bytes) in size, while [SHA-2 may go from 224 to 512 bits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Hash_Algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

sha-1 is 40 characters in the hexidecimal representation:
9BE083742A3494DD4DEE4904451AECE5394F5BAA

sha-2 will be longer.
sha-256 is one example of sha-2 and has hexidecimal representation of 32 characters:

C3F41471B1E8C1505C8E4AC766E972FC108262EAA45CC1F30FAC8154B0BBF79D

sha-512 is also sha-2 and it is, well, however many this is (128 characters):

489a101ad927ba19a9ed4442339b27498b870d53b8fad2b701e6a3e41e2e2b36b0208b092ea88239474dfeb732793a9695ad47d12e601569061a581c997de2cb